# Where can I get a USB connector without the data pins?

Tags: usb, mifi

I'd like to find a way to use USB to charge my MiFi device. Right now the standard USB connection turns on the 3G connectivity but does not charge at the same time. Meanwhile if I use the wall charger which came with it the WiFi hotspot is active while it charges. I would like to do the same while connected to my laptop.

I have a 3 inch USB connector which I prefer for portability but it only charges randomly. I cannot force it into charge mode.

My MiFi is a Novatel 2200 branded for Virgin Mobile. I read on their support site from another user that you can use a USB connector without data pins to just supply power to the device so it charges the battery.

How can I find a USB connector without data pins?

---

(rant) It is too hard to find USB hardware. I wish there were keywords for each type of USB connector so that when I search online I could just use a simple keyword to find the exact connector I needed. Searching for Micro A or Mini B does not narrow down the results very well since A and B are just ignored. (rant over)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just found this charger which is a great portable option. I hope it charges while it is active. http://www.amazon.com/Coiled-Novatel-Wireless-Charge-capabilities/dp/B003X5KIRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put some tape on the inner two contacts on the cable. Those are the data pins.
2. Get one of those [battery chargers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016Y9R6C), turn it on and leave it plugged into your MiFi and the computer. Makeshift, but works awesomely and has the added bonus that you don't have to leave it plugged in some of the time.
3. Try [this hack](http://www.jkkmobile.com/2009/06/how-to-usb-charger-hack-for-novatel.html) if you're really annoyed by this.

Answer (score 0):

Some USB-powered external hard drives come with a 3-plug cable, of which only 2 (one for the host, one for the drive) actually carry data. The third only carries power, and is for use with a host that doesn't supply enough power on only a single USB port.

Answer (score 0):

Acc...
That's quite a question...

What about buying a normal one and hacking it?
Read this article: it might be of help :)

> Standard USB Pinout Looking at a
>   standard A plug head on with pins up,
>   the pins are numbered backwards from 4
>   to 1. Pin 4 is the -5 volt lead, pin 3
>   is the + polarity data pin, 2 is the -
>   polarity data pin, and pin 1 is the +5
>   volt lead. Standard B plugs are a bit
>   different due to shape. The plug is
>   square, with bevels for the top
>   corners. There are two pins on top,
>   and two pins on bottom. The order is
>   clockwise starting top left, 1 through
>   4. 1 is +5 volt lead, 2 is + polarity data, 3 is - polarity data, and 4 is
>   -5 volt lead.
>
> Read more: What Is the Pin
>   Configuration for USB Connectors? |
>   eHow.com
>   http://www.ehow.com/facts_6371382_pin-configuration-usb-connectors_.html#ixzz181ix54fv

Answer (score 0):

These leads are charge only (allegedly) - will one connector fit your device?

http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.34674

Comment: Be careful with "charge only" if your device has a USB port; some of them connect the data pins regardless.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a bit much to carry around in my laptop bag. This what I would like to get if it would just not have the data pins. http://www.camera-news.com/images/pictures/bone-collection-usb-link-type-a-male-to-mini-usb-connecter-black-ap06031bk.jpg